# How to aggregate time series data on a postgres table for abitrary time range such that the returned result has no more than 100 rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

The table `statuses` has 3 columns

- id (uuid, PK)
- time (timestamp with time zone, NOT NULL)
- duration (integer, NOT NULL)

The records it contains are not evenly distributed; there could be a single record in a day or thousands in some other day.

I need to aggregate the duration (average) for any arbitrary time range such that the returned result has no more than 100 records.

Had it been grouping by day or by hour, it would have been pretty straightforward. But what's throwing me off a bit is the arbitrary time range and finding that sweet spot so the records are within the limit.

Example:

Actual data:

| time | duration |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-06-30 03:49:43+00 | 96 |
| 2023-06-30 03:51:25+00 | 132 |
| 2023-06-30 03:51:55+00 | 124 |
| 2023-06-30 03:52:25+00 | 102 |
| 2023-06-30 03:52:55+00 | 119 |
| 2023-06-30 03:53:25+00 | 136 |
| 2023-06-30 03:53:55+00 | 92 |
| 2023-06-30 03:54:25+00 | 86 |
| 2023-06-30 03:54:55+00 | 99 |
| 2023-06-30 03:55:25+00 | 105 |
| 2023-06-30 03:55:55+00 | 94 |
| 2023-06-30 03:56:25+00 | 76 |
| 2023-06-30 03:56:55+00 | 77 |
| 2023-06-30 03:57:25+00 | 66 |
| 2023-06-30 03:57:55+00 | 80 |
| 2023-06-30 03:59:13+00 | 98 |
| 2023-06-30 03:59:43+00 | 201 |
| 2023-06-30 04:00:13+00 | 652 |
| 2023-06-30 04:00:43+00 | 154 |
| 2023-06-30 04:01:13+00 | 272 |

Assuming, I want at most 10 output (instead of 100 as originally mentioned in the question), I would expect the following output

| time | duration |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-06-30 03:49:43+00 | 114 |
| 2023-06-30 03:51:55+00 | 113 |
| 2023-06-30 03:52:55+00 | 127.5 |
| 2023-06-30 03:53:55+00 | 89.0 |
| ...6 more rows |  |

Comment: Would `percent_rank` be useful for you here? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-window.html. You would need to scan all the data in the range, sorted by date+id give it a percent-rank and use that as a sub-query/cte source for the outer group-by.

Comment: What is this trying to achieve? I am not seeing how the information returned would be useful.

Comment: @AdrianKalver, the table represents a single run of a job. The duration is how long it took to run the job. There are thousands of these statuses for a job. I need these statuses to plot a graph and fetching all of them can be expensive. Which is why I want to average them and limit to 100 data points at max.

Comment: Still not making sense. You will need to provide some example input data and expected output. **Add as update to question**.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have added input and expected output. The data in the example happens to be evenly distrubuted (30 sec apart) but that may not always be the case

Comment: Pretty sure you are looking for a [Window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html)  with `lead()` from here [Window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want (obviously you'd substitute 'x' and 'y' for the limits of your date range):

```
with data_set as (select duration from table where time between 'x' and  'y' LIMIT 100)
select avg(duration)
from data_set
;
```

If this isn't what you want, can you update your question with some sample data and the result you want to achieve?

**Solution 2**

The following code divides the range of timestamps into 10 equal buckets (using the WIDTH_BUCKET function) and then averages all the durations for records that fall into each bucket - and uses the minimum timestamp in each bucket as a (semi-arbitrary) time to assign to the average.

To actually get 10 records there needs to be data for each "bucket" - so data needs to be relatively evenly distributed between the min and max timestamp. If it isn't, you can create your own arbitrary-sized buckets using the 3 parameter version of WIDTH_BUCKET where the 3rd parameter is an array of the lower bounds for each bucket.

I've split the code into multiple CTEs to make it clearer what it is doing - you could probably combine some of them  to shorten the code.

```
with data1 as (
  select 
    *, 
    cast(to_char((event_time):: TIMESTAMP, 'yyyymmddhhmiss') as BigInt) event_time_int 
  from 
    event_data
), 
data2 as (
  select 
    *, 
    (select min(event_time_int) from data1) min_ts, 
    (select max(event_time_int) from data1) max_ts 
  from data1
), 
data3 as (
  select 
    *, width_bucket(event_time_int, min_ts, max_ts, 10) bucket 
  from data2
) 
select 
  min(event_time), 
  avg(event_duration) 
from 
  data3 
group by 
  bucket;
```

Comment: This is just selecting the first 100 data. What I want is 100 data points but as a result of an aggregation. So if I have 400 data points then 4 would be aggregated to represent a single data point resulting in 100 total data points

Comment: How are you determining that the data is actually representative of anything? You need 100 values in your GROUP BY field  so are you just dividing your date range into 100 equal buckets? If not, how do you expect this to work?

Comment: The second solution is close to what I want (although I noticed one of the record being put into bucket 11 even though I need just 10 as passed in the width_bucket func). Wasn't aware of `width_bucket` but that seems to be the perfect func that I need here.

Answer (score 0):

Using window functions with `lead`.

```
create table job_table(line_id integer generated always as identity, ts timestamptz, duration integer);

insert into job_table(ts, duration) values
(' 2023-06-30 03:49:43+00 ', 96),
(' 2023-06-30 03:51:25+00 ', 132),
(' 2023-06-30 03:51:55+00 ', 124),
(' 2023-06-30 03:52:25+00 ', 102),
(' 2023-06-30 03:52:55+00 ', 119),
(' 2023-06-30 03:53:25+00 ', 136),
(' 2023-06-30 03:53:55+00 ', 92 ),
(' 2023-06-30 03:54:25+00 ', 86 ),
(' 2023-06-30 03:54:55+00 ', 99 ),
(' 2023-06-30 03:55:25+00 ', 105),
(' 2023-06-30 03:55:55+00 ', 94 ),
(' 2023-06-30 03:56:25+00 ', 76 ),
(' 2023-06-30 03:56:55+00 ', 77 ),
(' 2023-06-30 03:57:25+00 ', 66 ),
(' 2023-06-30 03:57:55+00 ', 80 ),
(' 2023-06-30 03:59:13+00 ', 98 ),
(' 2023-06-30 03:59:43+00 ', 201),
(' 2023-06-30 04:00:13+00 ', 652),
(' 2023-06-30 04:00:43+00 ', 154),
(' 2023-06-30 04:01:13+00 ', 272); 

select 
    ts, round((duration + lead(duration) over(order by ts))/2.0, 2) 
from 
    job_table 
where 
   ts between '2023-06-30 03:49:43+00' and ' 2023-06-30 04:01:13+00' 
limit 10;

           ts            | duration 
-------------------------+----------
 06/29/2023 20:49:43 PDT |   114.00
 06/29/2023 20:51:25 PDT |   128.00
 06/29/2023 20:51:55 PDT |   113.00
 06/29/2023 20:52:25 PDT |   110.50
 06/29/2023 20:52:55 PDT |   127.50
 06/29/2023 20:53:25 PDT |   114.00
 06/29/2023 20:53:55 PDT |    89.00
 06/29/2023 20:54:25 PDT |    92.50
 06/29/2023 20:54:55 PDT |   102.00
 06/29/2023 20:55:25 PDT |    99.50
```

Comment: I'm losing data this way which i don't want. If there are 1000 data points I need to summarize all of them; that would be by averaging the first 10 into 1 data point, and then the next 10 data points to another data point and so on. Ultimately, I solved it by dividing the date range into 100 parts and then putting all the data points into the closest "window" and then simply grouping them. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have this time series as input: 3 hour's worth of data, unevenly distributed:

```
SELECT
  TRUNC(ts,'hh') AS thehour
, count(*) as rc
FROM tseries
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
-- out        thehour       | rc 
-- out ---------------------+----
-- out  2023-07-01 00:00:00 | 44
-- out  2023-07-01 01:00:00 | 35
-- out  2023-07-01 02:00:00 | 21
```

The data look like this: ...

```
         ts          |  nam   
---------------------+--------
 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | row 00
 2023-07-01 00:01:00 | row 01
 2023-07-01 00:03:00 | row 02
 2023-07-01 00:04:00 | row 03
[. . .]
 2023-07-01 02:42:00 | row 96
 2023-07-01 02:45:00 | row 97
 2023-07-01 02:47:00 | row 98
 2023-07-01 02:56:00 | row 99
(100 rows)
```

All I do is to get a row number column, which tells me whether the row is the first, second, third, etc row if we order by the timestamp. And a second step is to integer-divide this row number by 10 - in my example (and by 100 in your example) to get a grouping criterion. Like this:

```
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ts) AS rn
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ts) / 10 AS grp
  , *
  FROM tseries
 rn  | grp |         ts          |  nam   
-----+-----+---------------------+--------
   1 |   0 | 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | row 00
   2 |   0 | 2023-07-01 00:01:00 | row 01
   3 |   0 | 2023-07-01 00:03:00 | row 02
   4 |   0 | 2023-07-01 00:04:00 | row 03
[. . .]
   9 |   0 | 2023-07-01 00:08:00 | row 08
  10 |   1 | 2023-07-01 00:10:00 | row 09
  11 |   1 | 2023-07-01 00:10:00 | row 10
[. . .]
  96 |   9 | 2023-07-01 02:39:00 | row 95
  97 |   9 | 2023-07-01 02:42:00 | row 96
  98 |   9 | 2023-07-01 02:45:00 | row 97
  99 |   9 | 2023-07-01 02:47:00 | row 98
 100 |  10 | 2023-07-01 02:56:00 | row 99
```

Then, I can group by the `grp` column in an outside query; and when I add a `LEAD()` function call to the inner query, I have the choice to subtract the minimal timestamp of the group from the maximal timestamp of the group, or from the maximal `next_ts` of the group:

```
WITH
w_rn AS (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER w      AS rn
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER w / 10 AS grp
  , LEAD(ts)     OVER w      AS next_ts
  , *
  FROM tseries
  WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY ts)
)
SELECT
  grp
, MIN(ts)                AS start_ts
, MAX(ts)                AS end_ts
, MAX(next_ts)           AS next_ts
, MAX(ts) - MIN(ts)      AS duration_inside
, MAX(next_ts) - MIN(ts) AS duration_outside
FROM w_rn
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
 grp |      start_ts       |       end_ts        |       next_ts       | duration_inside | duration_outside 
-----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+------------------
   0 | 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | 2023-07-01 00:08:00 | 2023-07-01 00:10:00 | 00:08:00        | 00:10:00
   1 | 2023-07-01 00:10:00 | 2023-07-01 00:27:00 | 2023-07-01 00:31:00 | 00:17:00        | 00:21:00
   2 | 2023-07-01 00:31:00 | 2023-07-01 00:43:00 | 2023-07-01 00:44:00 | 00:12:00        | 00:13:00
   3 | 2023-07-01 00:44:00 | 2023-07-01 00:52:00 | 2023-07-01 00:55:00 | 00:08:00        | 00:11:00
   4 | 2023-07-01 00:55:00 | 2023-07-01 01:10:00 | 2023-07-01 01:10:00 | 00:15:00        | 00:15:00
   5 | 2023-07-01 01:10:00 | 2023-07-01 01:35:00 | 2023-07-01 01:40:00 | 00:25:00        | 00:30:00
   6 | 2023-07-01 01:40:00 | 2023-07-01 01:48:00 | 2023-07-01 01:50:00 | 00:08:00        | 00:10:00
   7 | 2023-07-01 01:50:00 | 2023-07-01 01:59:00 | 2023-07-01 02:02:00 | 00:09:00        | 00:12:00
   8 | 2023-07-01 02:02:00 | 2023-07-01 02:21:00 | 2023-07-01 02:23:00 | 00:19:00        | 00:21:00
   9 | 2023-07-01 02:23:00 | 2023-07-01 02:47:00 | 2023-07-01 02:56:00 | 00:24:00        | 00:33:00
  10 | 2023-07-01 02:56:00 | 2023-07-01 02:56:00 | (null)              | 00:00:00        | (null)
(11 rows)
```

Please *do* scroll the last report to the right to see how it calculates.

Comment: "it would go from 1 to 100 - we have 100 rows in the table" I am not sure I quite follow, The table would have far more rows than just 100.

Comment: I created an example with 100 rows. The solution would work for an infinite number of rows. I split by groups of 10 instead of groups of 100. Again, all you have to do is to integer-divide the row-number by 100 instead of 10. I'll edit the answer to illustrate

Answer (score 0):

The following query demonstrates using `ntile` to aggregate time series data with irregular intervals into buckets:

```
WITH statuses(start_time, duration) AS (
  VALUES ('2023-06-30 03:49:43+00'::timestamptz, 96),
         ('2023-06-30 03:51:25+00'::timestamptz, 132),
         ('2023-06-30 03:51:55+00'::timestamptz, 124),
         ('2023-06-30 03:52:25+00'::timestamptz, 102),
         ('2023-06-30 03:52:55+00'::timestamptz, 119),
         ('2023-06-30 03:53:25+00'::timestamptz, 136),
         ('2023-06-30 03:53:55+00'::timestamptz, 92),
         ('2023-06-30 03:54:25+00'::timestamptz, 86),
         ('2023-06-30 03:54:55+00'::timestamptz, 99),
         ('2023-06-30 03:55:25+00'::timestamptz, 105),
         ('2023-06-30 03:55:55+00'::timestamptz, 94),
         ('2023-06-30 03:56:25+00'::timestamptz, 76),
         ('2023-06-30 03:56:55+00'::timestamptz, 77),
         ('2023-06-30 03:57:25+00'::timestamptz, 66),
         ('2023-06-30 03:57:55+00'::timestamptz, 80),
         ('2023-06-30 03:59:13+00'::timestamptz, 98),
         ('2023-06-30 03:59:43+00'::timestamptz, 201),
         ('2023-06-30 04:00:13+00'::timestamptz, 652),
         ('2023-06-30 04:00:43+00'::timestamptz, 154),
         ('2023-06-30 04:01:13+00'::timestamptz, 272)),
buckets AS (
  SELECT statuses.*, ntile(10) OVER (ORDER BY statuses.start_time) AS bucket
    FROM statuses)
SELECT buckets.bucket, min(buckets.start_time) AS start_time, avg(buckets.duration) AS mean_duration
  FROM buckets
  GROUP BY buckets.bucket
  ORDER BY buckets.bucket;
```

The argument to `ntile` determines the maximum number of buckets. There will never be more buckets than data points. Running the preceding query results in the following output:

```
 bucket |       start_time       |    mean_duration     
--------+------------------------+----------------------
      1 | 2023-06-29 23:49:43-04 | 114.0000000000000000
      2 | 2023-06-29 23:51:55-04 | 113.0000000000000000
      3 | 2023-06-29 23:52:55-04 | 127.5000000000000000
      4 | 2023-06-29 23:53:55-04 |  89.0000000000000000
      5 | 2023-06-29 23:54:55-04 | 102.0000000000000000
      6 | 2023-06-29 23:55:55-04 |  85.0000000000000000
      7 | 2023-06-29 23:56:55-04 |  71.5000000000000000
      8 | 2023-06-29 23:57:55-04 |  89.0000000000000000
      9 | 2023-06-29 23:59:43-04 | 426.5000000000000000
     10 | 2023-06-30 00:00:43-04 | 213.0000000000000000
(10 rows)
```

Adding a time range to the `buckets` subquery efficiently limits the data points included in the buckets.